# foreach inside tokenize

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

This is a snippet from the xml:

```
<sample>
        <test>
            <Cell1>John</Cell1>
            <Cell2>A</Cell2>
            <Cell4>xy</Cell4>
        </test>
        <test>
            <Cell1>Jack</Cell1>
            <Cell2>B</Cell2>
            <Cell3>Red</Cell3>
            <Cell6>10</Cell6>
        </test>
        <test>
            <Cell1>John,Jade</Cell1>
            <Cell2>A,Y</Cell2>
            <Cell4>1</Cell4>
        </test>
        <test>
            <Cell1>John,Jade</Cell1>
            <Cell2>A B,X</Cell2>
            <Cell3>Blue</Cell3>
        </test>
    </sample>
```

### Conditions:

If `Cell2` contains comma split the values and check if the preceding `Cell2` contains the same value and similarly if `Cell2` contains space split the values and check if the preceding `Cell2` contains the same value -> If so ignore it.

This is how I want the output:

```
<Cell2>A</Cell2>
<Cell2>B</Cell2>
<Cell2>Y</Cell2>
<Cell2>X</Cell2>
```

This is the xslt which I wrote: (please look into the comment)

```
<xsl:template match="sample">
        <xsl:for-each select="test">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(Cell2,',')">
                        <xsl:variable name="token1Cell2" select="tokenize(Cell2,',')"/>
                        <xsl:for-each select="$token1Cell2">
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="contains(.,' ')">
                                    <xsl:variable name="token2Cell2" select="tokenize(.,' ')"/>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="$token2Cell2">
              <!-- I tried to check if the preceding sibling element test/Cell2 contains the text that is not equal to the current text. But I know what I am doing is wrong as I am inside for-each tokenize. How to get the preceding-sibling? -->
                                      <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::test/
Cell2/text() != '.'">
                                        <Cell2>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                        </Cell2>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::test/Cell2/text() != '.'">
                                    <Cell2>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                    </Cell2>
                                </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <Cell2>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Cell2"/>
                        </Cell2>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

How Can I acheive the output? Any Ideas??

Answer (score 6):

**Just this simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(/*/test/Cell2/tokenize(.,'[ ,]'))">
      <Cell2><xsl:value-of select="."/></Cell2>
     </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<sample>
    <test>
        <Cell1>John</Cell1>
        <Cell2>A</Cell2>
        <Cell4>xy</Cell4>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Cell1>Jack</Cell1>
        <Cell2>B</Cell2>
        <Cell3>Red</Cell3>
        <Cell6>10</Cell6>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Cell1>John,Jade</Cell1>
        <Cell2>A,Y</Cell2>
        <Cell4>1</Cell4>
    </test>
    <test>
        <Cell1>John,Jade</Cell1>
        <Cell2>A B,X</Cell2>
        <Cell3>Blue</Cell3>
    </test>
</sample>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Cell2>A</Cell2>
<Cell2>B</Cell2>
<Cell2>Y</Cell2>
<Cell2>X</Cell2>
```

**Explanation**:

The XPath expression in the `select` attribute of `xsl:for-each` is the key to understand:

```
distinct-values(/*/test/Cell2/tokenize(.,'[ ,]'))
```

This produces the distinct values of the sequence of all tokenized (string values of) `/*/test/Cell2`

Answer (score 4):

For a start, if you are tokenizing on either a comma or a space, then you could combine your tokenize into one expression

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',|\s')">
```

What you could do, is first match all **Cell2** elements, with your template tokenizing the contents, but put the results in a variable

```
  <xsl:variable name="cells">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="test/Cell2"/>
  </xsl:variable>
```

Then you could simply use the **xsl:for-each-group** to iterate over them

```
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$cells/Cell2" group-by="text()">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="sample">
      <xsl:variable name="cells">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="test/Cell2"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$cells/Cell2" group-by="text()">
         <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Cell2">
      <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(., ',|\s')">
         <Cell2>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </Cell2>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<Cell2>A</Cell2>
<Cell2>B</Cell2>
<Cell2>Y</Cell2>
<Cell2>X</Cell2>
```

Comment: TimC, the version attribute must be "2.0". And @Shil, there is a much simpler solution.

Comment: Ah yes, I have corrected that. And yes, your solution is much simpler!

Answer (score 2):

When you have deeply nested xsl:for-each instructions, the context item changes at each level, so you often need to bind a variable to the context item at each level so you can get back to it. However, deeply-nested xsl:for-each instructions are sometimes an indication that you should be breaking up your code into smaller templates or functions.